# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'embedding' (type Functional)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I aqm trying to create a facial recognition AI to recognize who I am and when it does it will show me my name. but I keep getting this error about the "embedding layer" I cant seem to solve this. I put the error in the image below. Someone please help!
Heres the error

[image: this is the error]

My code:

```
#Import standard dependicies
import cv2
import os
import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Import Tensorflow dependencies - Functional API
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Conv2D, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Input, Flatten
import tensorflow as tf 
import uuid
#Avoid out of memory errors by setting GPU Memory consumption Growth
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')

for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

for gpu in gpus:
    print(gpu)

# Setup paths
POS_PATH = os.path.join('data', 'positive')
NEG_PATH = os.path.join('data', 'negative')
ANC_PATH = os.path.join('data' ,'anchor')

#Make the Dirs
#os.makedirs(POS_PATH)
#os.makedirs(NEG_PATH)
#os.makedirs(ANC_PATH)

#move lfw images to the data/negative
#for directory in os.listdir('lfw'):
    #for file in os.listdir(os.path.join('lfw', directory)):
       #EX_PATH = os.path.join('lfw', directory, file)
       #NEW_PATH = os.path.join(NEG_PATH,  file)
       #os.replace(EX_PATH, NEW_PATH)


captureDevice = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #captureDevice = camera

while True:
    ret, frame = captureDevice.read() 

    #cuts frame down to 250x250
    frame = frame[120:120+250,200:200+250, :]

    #collect anchors
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
        # Creates a unique file path
        imgname = os.path.join(ANC_PATH, '{}.jpg'.format(uuid.uuid1()))
        # Write out anchor image
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)


    #collec positives
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('p'):
     # Creates a unique file path
     imgname = os.path.join(POS_PATH, '{}.jpg'.format(uuid.uuid1()))
     # Write out anchor image
     cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)

    cv2.imshow('Intrusion ML Space', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

captureDevice.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

anchor = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(ANC_PATH+'\*.jpg').take(300)
positive = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(POS_PATH+'\*.jpg').take(300)
negative = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(NEG_PATH+'\*.jpg').take(300)

dir_test = anchor.as_numpy_iterator()

print(dir_test.next())

def preprocess(file_path):
    byte_img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_jpg(byte_img)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (100,100))
    img = img / 255.0
    return img




positives = tf.data.Dataset.zip((anchor, positive, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.ones(len(anchor)))))
negatives = tf.data.Dataset.zip((anchor, negative, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.zeros(len(anchor)))))
data = positives.concatenate(negatives)

def preoprocess_twin(input_img, validation_img, label):
    return(preprocess(input_img), preprocess(validation_img), label)

    # Build data loader pipeline
    data = data.map(preprocess_twin)
    data = data.cache()
    data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=1024)



# Training partition
train_data = data.take(round(len(data)*.7))
train_data = train_data.batch(16)
train_data = train_data.prefetch(8)

train_samples = train_data.as_numpy_iterator()
train_sample = train_samples.next()
len(train_sample[0])

# TEsting partition
test_data = data.skip(round(len(data)*.7))
test_data = test_data.take(round(len(data)*.3))
test_data = test_data.batch(16)
test_data = test_data.prefetch(8)

#Making embedding layer
inp = Input(shape=(100,100,3), name='input_image')
c1 = Conv2D(64, (10,10), activation='relu')(inp)

m1 = MaxPooling2D(64, (2,2), padding='same')(c1)
c2 = Conv2D(128, (7,7), activation='relu')(m1)

m2 = MaxPooling2D(64, (2,2), padding='same')(c2)
c3 = Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu')(m2)

m3 = MaxPooling2D(64, (2,2), padding='same')(c3)
c4 = Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu')(m3)

f1 = Flatten()(c4)
d1 = Dense(4096, activation='sigmoid')(f1)
mod = Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[d1], name='embedding')

def make_embedding(): 
    inp = Input(shape=(100,100,3), name='input_image')
    
    # First block
    c1 = Conv2D(64, (10,10), activation='relu')(inp)
    m1 = MaxPooling2D(64, (2,2), padding='same')(c1)
    
    # Second block
    c2 = Conv2D(128, (7,7), activation='relu')(m1)
    m2 = MaxPooling2D(64, (2,2), padding='same')(c2)
    
    # Third block 
    c3 = Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu')(m2)
    m3 = MaxPooling2D(64, (2,2), padding='same')(c3)
    
    # Final embedding block
    c4 = Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu')(m3)
    f1 = Flatten()(c4)
    d1 = Dense(4096, activation='sigmoid')(f1)
    
    
    return Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[d1], name='embedding')

embedding = make_embedding()


# Siamese L1 Distance class
class L1Dist(Layer):
    
    # Init method - inheritance
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
       
    # Magic happens here - similarity calculation
    def call(self, input_embedding, validation_embedding):
        return tf.math.abs(input_embedding - validation_embedding)

l1 = L1Dist()


input_image = Input(name='input_img', shape=(100,100,3))
validation_image = Input(name='validation_img', shape=(100,100,3))

inp_embedding = embedding(input_image)

val_embedding = embedding(validation_image)

siamese_layer = L1Dist()

distances = siamese_layer(inp_embedding, val_embedding)

classifier = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(distances)


#Siamese Model
def make_siamese_model(): 
    
    # Anchor image input in the network
    input_image = Input(name='input_img', shape=(100,100,3))
    
    # Validation image in the network 
    validation_image = Input(name='validation_img', shape=(100,100,3))
    
    # Combine siamese distance components
    siamese_layer = L1Dist()
    siamese_layer._name = 'distance'
    distances = siamese_layer(embedding(input_image), embedding(validation_image))
    
    # Classification layer 
    classifier = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(distances)
    
    return Model(inputs=[input_image, validation_image], outputs=classifier, name='SiameseNetwork')


siamese_model = make_siamese_model()

siamese_model.summary()

#setup the Loss and Optimizer

binary_cross_loss = tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)

#Establish Checkpoints
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, 'ckpt')
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(opt=opt, siamese_model=siamese_model)


test_batch = train_data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch_1 = test_batch.next()
X = batch_1[:2]
y = batch_1[2]

@tf.function
def train_step(batch):
    
    # Record all of our operations 
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:     
        # Get anchor and positive/negative image
        X = batch[:2]
        # Get label
        y = batch[2]
        
        # Forward pass
        yhat = siamese_model(X, training=True)
        # Calculate loss
        loss = binary_cross_loss(y, yhat)
    print(loss)
        
    # Calculate gradients
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, siamese_model.trainable_variables)
    
    # Calculate updated weights and apply to siamese model
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, siamese_model.trainable_variables))
        
    # Return loss
    return loss


# Import metric calculations
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Precision, Recall

def train(data, EPOCHS):
    # Loop through epochs
    for epoch in range(1, EPOCHS+1):
        print('\n Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, EPOCHS))
        progbar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(len(data))
        
        # Creating a metric object 
        r = Recall()
        p = Precision()
        
        # Loop through each batch
        for idx, batch in enumerate(data):
            # Run train step here
            loss = train_step(batch)
            yhat = siamese_model.predict(batch[:2])
            r.update_state(batch[2], yhat)
            p.update_state(batch[2], yhat) 
            progbar.update(idx+1)
        print(loss.numpy(), r.result().numpy(), p.result().numpy())
        
        # Save checkpoints
        if epoch % 10 == 0: 
            checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix)




EPOCHS = 50
train(train_data, EPOCHS)
```

Which part did I mess up on? Also how do I fix it?